# Is this encrypted information? Why is it in a URL?

Tags: encryption, hash, email

There's a vendor who sends us reports full of links to articles. Some of these links, especially ones that perform what I'm guessing is an HTTP verb of some kind, look like this:

`https://arbitrarynumbers.acronym.website.com/anotheracronym/click?upn=V7nLa9UXJ-2FC89NDFn1UZlmMFXDCeN8q0tH6mY545KyAUaP8HmDtN9T2S-2Bg7aCCMBlSZh11liPowfKxWPna-2FVaptFLOZxqpcD68QrcptgMI1a22Y4XTEZiAeucUWjZAD9sVgV-2Baq0xequM7VcXl-2BmOl3FWqf7MOfWK13WhAyY6ILWhLP7aq99cI0yTYqdDXyfbGSCsAH14unM0mJZPPrnkibqRXOK6AicnwpYyUYWHrrglFkTEp1NUhfexGsfqdAypWPJVWibehmCua8elVvEK3h5UWGEQ-2BcMNXEYYaHh2Mk7e6P0PrboAZkrlVqjZw81_Vf68ZJ5AeUI3LF4CqINVwnqFVd-2FKRV7eRgp7NmpHn0vrNNp-2FS8Dx205CxtKAt8ruN8Tea80o1B2D68NmTEQrbzQbGcouV7k1BM7OghNe6LlIGeA-2B0g3cElmWBAQdEdnWI2eNmj-2FBye8kH4PB-2Bvp5GZihoTPLDhFLu31kSFdBGD5teoPbI-2FY26oYvi9TEWxcsvMtu3BS8V7aM0tKWV6h5D3IUQyv0cgY4liePEMplxsByyFEgJd5mgDyGiI4fFJgxPk529v0OuvuEDbPptklLF1LBT-2F-2Bt-2FOtOcTc-2BgfNAvLEHB8Rizid3vB6a6wd-2FG1PdK8fpMergoZPBy8DG3t143bUrabzZ-2BOvKN5bfzdOO80A-3D` (This particular link is one you click to tell them the article wasn't relevant.)

Is this some attempt at hashing or encrypting the contents of the URL so people can't just send them random `HTTP DELETE` commands, or similar? Or is it some kind of security-by-obscurity? Something else entirely?

Comment: Probably this hash doesn't contains personal information, just some informations about localization and referral

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The link propably contains the full url of the article that wasnt relevant, and also user details of the user that sends "this is not relevant", so only those that received the report can tell that "this is not relevant".

Its not security-by-obscurity, rather, its a link with authentication data embedded, so you don't have to type your username/password or ask the company manager to tell "this is not relevant".

The reason to encrypt the url also, is that a integrity-verifying code at the end, can ensure, that authentication data belongning to link 1 cannot be misused to link 2. Eg, when you have clicked that link, then the corresponding article is then marked as not relevant. If some unauthorized individual clicks the link again, it does not matter since the article is already marked as not relevant.

The encryption then prevents someone from changing the article url/article id inside the link so one link cannot be misused to mark another article as not relevant, or misusing the link for other things like unsubscribing or such.

Think the link as this:
http://example.org/auth?username=somebody&password=somepassw0rd&action=markasnotrelevant&url=http://www.somenewssite.com/article/article39587395837u59.html&hash=5acf768c5fcafac85afc785fc8c
and then you encrypt that with a symmetric algoritm, and then encode as urlsafe base64, before sending it out.
Since the server created the encrypted link, the server can also decrypt the information with the same symmetric key, but nobody can abuse the information stored in the link.

It has NOTHING to do with DELETE/PUT and such HTTP verbs. A browser is normally unable to send anything else than GET/HEAD/POST, so the request done is a GET in the above case.

Comment: So then this is a completely legitimate form of security for such situations, not just something hacked together to serve a purpose? I'm curious because I've never seen/noticed URLs composed this way before.

Comment: yes. But they are used in other cases too. For example as email-verify in user registration, you can put the contents of the registration form in such a encrypted link, to avoid having to store anything in database before email is verified. But yes, such links are uncommon, its more common to store a random ID in a database, with fields corresponding to user details and URL and such, and then just have the ID in the link. But such solution does not scale well since then every link ever sent out needs to be stored in database.

Comment: Looking at the parameter name "upn" I think it's more likely to be a claims token identifying the user. Similar idea but hopefully without anything like a password in there :)

Comment: Yes but the link must contain the article to be marked as not relevant too. And even if there were a password/password hash there, it would be no harm. That would actually increase security, since if the user changes password, all previous links are automatically invalidated.

Comment: Could be! The last acronym on the URL could be the article, but there's nothing obvious to indicate the desired action. It seems unlikely that "click" == "not relevant"

Comment: It is really "click" == "not relevant". Note that the link is encrypted. All the parameters in the link exist there before encrypting. Thats why the URL is so long, because it contains multiple long parameters, that is then encrypted with a symmetric key, before sent out as a link. Base64 encoding also extends the length with 33 % too, as base64 can only store 6 bits per character, and a encrypted message uses all 8 bits in each character. So such encrypted links can get very long, and in some cases they can be troubling since some browsers have a max-length on urls.

Comment: Is there a better way to handle these types of systems?

Comment: Now I don't understand what you meant with "better way", but in the security point of view, I would say this is enough.